# forwarding to struts jsp works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts

having some serious headaches with struts. Using Tomcat here..
After investigating the application logs i'm puzzled...

I hit an action for example as such:
https://www.testkisses.ca/service/stats.a?lang=en

Once this action is hit, it performs its logic (goes to the database and performs the expected functionality)

at the end it sends the user to a JSP.

I forward to the JSP as such:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("statsPrefBean", statsBean);
return mapping.findForward("stats");
```

in the struts XML I have defined this action as:

```
<action path="/stats" type="web.promotions.Stats" name="Test" scope="request" validate="false" input="input">
    <forward name="statscanada" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/product/statscan.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Even though I do not use "Test" or "input" anywhere in the jsp (unsure if that is affecting it).

The scenario is that the action is always hit and the functionality is performed, yet sometimes I get a 404 error and sometimes I get the expected successful page.

**Might anyone have any idea why in certain situations it gives me a 404? and why in most situations it works?**

Comment: mapping.findforward is stats forward name is statsCanada should match right?

Comment: I know you're probably just fixing legacy code, but... using struts1 in 2015 is just *wrong*.